# Is it ok to answer questions with just a link

Tags: discussion, answers, link-only-answers

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)
>   [Why is linking bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/why-is-linking-bad)

Is it okay to answer questions like this (name blanked out):

[image]

The answer happened to be relevant and useful, but what if the link no longer works?  Shouldn't you at least copy/paste te relevant part?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/why-is-linking-bad - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15625/is-downvoting-link-only-answers-acceptable

Comment: Aw, I wished so much to answer this with just a "No" linking each letter to those duplicates. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. You should always provide relevant text along with appropriate information about the source material (such as the name and date posted, if available).

I personally haven't always done this myself, but it's a good practice to capture relevant information without needing to click on links (other than to validate the material and get more information).

Comment: The biggest reason to do this is to make sure that the answer remains helpful even after the link dies, IMO.

Comment: @tvanosson: Of course, we aren't allowed to change our vote after the link dies to indicate that it's become a bad answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would usually explain some detail as to what is at the link. It gives the reader some idea of whether it will be relevant or interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes as it does allow you to save the answer, and it may provide relevant information concerning the question.  Most people like seeing more information than just a link.  The best answers are the ones which provide the link and then give and explanation as to what it says/why it's relevant.