# Right way to mark material "quoted" from other sources?

Tags: discussion, attribution

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8496874/643383) to the question [NSView's bounds vs frame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8496762/643383) includes some text quoted from Apple's *[View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW6)*. It also contains a very helpful image borrowed from the same source.

Now, I quote text from Apple's documentation (and other places) all the time, and I generally include a link back to the source document and expect that that's enough attribution to make reasonable people comfortable. But I wonder about the image. There's nothing in the answer that specifically attributes the image to Apple's document. What's the best way to indicate the source of the image in this situation? And is using an image like this even considered acceptable?

Some options that I've considered are:

1. Add a line after the image like: "(Image taken from *View Programming Guide*)".
2. Change the image URL from the current https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjt7r.jpg to the URL of the source image so that it's easier to tell where it comes from.
3. Replace the image with a description, like: "You'll find an image in the linked documentation that illustrates this point perfectly."
4. Create an original image that makes the same point.
5. Use the block quote syntax before the image, which puts the image in a gray box, possibly better conveying the idea that the image is a continuation of the quoted material above.

Comment: related (is this a dup?): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115816/how-should-i-attribute-excerpts-of-code-from-other-stack-overflow-posts

Comment: @JasonPlank That's certainly helpful, but I still don't know a) how to edit the linked answer to provide proper attribution, and b) whether including an image like that is acceptable.