# Linking to other web pages through stack overflow questions

Tags: discussion, etiquette, community-data

Thinking of a title for this question was difficult, but I here is the scenario,

Someone asks a question, and the answer to said question is in an article that is linked to in another stackoverflow question that is in my favorites list.  When I answer his question, should I link directly to the article, or should I link to the stack overflow question that links to the question?  What is better for the SO information database?

Comment: Tis a duplicate.

Comment: here's one http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/why-is-linking-bad

Comment: @ChrisF: I don't think that's the same question at all. That one is about whether links are good in general, but this one is about the best way to link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, I would link to both and then insert a relevant quote from the article. Something like:

> As referenced in [this answer][link], the solution to your problem can be found [here][link to article]. From the article:
>
> > Waffles are tasty
> >     But they can be better if
> >     You also toast them.

Comment: +1 for haiku.  and on general principles.

Comment: The quote is critical -- that article's link may very well change in the future. Get as much relevant info in your post as possible.

Comment: Waffles area tasty!  Accepted because its a good answer, and 1 upvote for waffles!