# Can we agree on a review 'policy'?

Tags: discussion, review, policy

On the [review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review), there is a one-sentence guideline on reviewing. I think that as the number of reviewers increase, it is going to become increasingly necessary to come to some kind of agreement about a standard way to handle the different 'cases' that arise.

I'm not sure if 'one question to rule them all' here is a good idea or not, but let's try.

Post an answer for each new 'type' of problem, with a suggested approach, then people can weigh in with comments and update the approach accordingly. Make the posts CW preferably.

*(Obviously, don't bother posting links to problem posts, as they won't be around long - just copy/paste any relevant text)*

**EDIT** IMPORTANT: There has been some  *(cough)*, 'confusion' about the semantics of 'flag for removal' in review. Some people took that to mean "this answer is ok, remove it from the reviewing list", whereas (as I understand it), it actually means "flag for removal from the site".

**EDIT2** - (Shameless plug) If you find the answers to this question helpful, you may be interested in my [Pro-forma comments script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/pro-forma-comments)

Comment: Maybe I'm crazy, but is this in any way necessary? /review doesn't create new problems/solutions, it just makes it easier to find bad posts -- the ways we've always dealt with those posts still apply

Comment: @Michael, maybe not. But I guess now that there is a review page, and people are being actively encouraged to go there, it would be good to draw together all the collective 'edition culture' that we've developed into one place for easy reference - not so much for the 'old hands', but to point new people to.

Comment: In general, if these are old posts, I wouldn't even bother commenting on them.

Comment: @MichaelMyers, yes, that's what @radp suggested in his answer.

Comment: Should this be community wiki?

Comment: This question and its answers are about collecting policies for reviewers.  It may be useful to have a parallel question/answers for end users.  For example, take the issue "Nothing but a URL, but does answer the question" - the example comment is good, but the linked question in the comment is exactly that - a question with a bunch of potential answers - may not be user friendly. It may be better to link to a nicely-edited, concise post that clearly explains the rationale behind why URL-only posts are bad. These posts would be collected in a meta question that holds all these faq-like posts.

Answer (score 20):

**Category**: Answers which should be comments (or votes, or accepts)

**Symptom**: Thanks

**Example**:

> Ah Matthew!! thank you so much! I
>   strugled the whole day with this...
>   never though about putting it in a
>   using block.
>
> I am really just a beginner and read a
>   few threads and just tried anything
>   really... and thnaks for the info,
>   took the Flush out, added the using
>   block, and everythings working
>   perfectly.
>
> Oh and the fast answer is much
>   appriciated!

**Policy**: Click through, comment 'this should be a comment' (see below), **flag**, (don't bother to down-vote if very low rep user?). If the user is the OP, also mention accepting. *There's no point commenting if the user hasn't been back in months*

**Example comment**:

```
[Optional: Welcome to SiteName!] Please don't add 'thanks' as answers. Invest 
some time in the site and you will gain sufficient 
[privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, 
which is the SiteName way of saying thank you.
```

**Notes**: Don't forget that low-rep users (https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) can't comment everywhere - only on their questions, and answers to their questions, and on their answers.

Comment: Thanks should be upvotes -- or even better, accepts :)

Comment: **Suggestion:** Welcome to *Site Name*! Please don't add 'thanks' as answers, the answerer will not be notified of your response. Instead, invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, and comment on them if you want to notify the answerer.

Comment: I disagree here. Thank you answers should be deleted, otherwise we teach low rep users that "thank you" answers are fine.

Comment: @waffles, you forget that we mere mortals can't delete answers :)

Comment: :) I think I misunderstood the symptom here ... If it is "Contains important information about the questions" I am totally for this policy. But if it is only a "thanks" well "flag for removal" makes more sense

Comment: @waffles, no, you're right, I've edited a bit to try and make things clearer.

Comment: After you flag the answer, **do you mark for removal from `/review`**?

Answer (score 12):

**Category**: Nothing but a URL

**Symptom**: *Does* actually answer the question

**Example**:

> 1: http://wiki.eclipse.org/J9? - try this

**Policy**: If someone else has actually provided a better answer, just downvote. If user is still active on site, leave a comment inviting them to provide more information (see below). Otherwise edit?

**Example comment**:

```
[Optional: Welcome to SiteName!] Whilst this does theoretically answer the 
question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) 
to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for 
reference.
```

**Alternatively**: If you're feeling generous, edit the answer into shape...

Comment: As a new user, I'd wonder why that is preferable.

Comment: @meriton: Good point. There are plenty of good reasons, to be found [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/why-is-linking-bad)

Comment: If you downvote/comment on the answer, **do you mark for removal from `/review`**? Obviously you would do so if you edited it to make it better...

Answer (score 9):

What I do when browsing low quality posts:

- If a new user posts a "bad" answer and his last visit was relatively recent (I'm thinking within 30 days), **comment.**

  > Welcome to *Site Name Here*! This is not a forum. In a few upvotes' time you'll be able to *Intended Action Here*; in the meantime, please use the "Post answer" button for actual answers only.

  or:

  > Welcome to *Site Name Here*! If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the ["Ask Question"](http://example.org/questions/ask?tags=tag1+tag2+tag3) *Shape of Ask Question Button Here*. I have taken the time to fill in the tags for you :)

  or:

  > Welcome to *Site Name Here*! If you would like to add further details to your question, feel free to use the "Edit" button below your original post instead and only use the "Post Answer" button for actual answers.
- If a new user posts a "bad" answer and his last visit was far back in the past (usually minutes after his post), **flag for removal**.
- If the post is low quality because of grammar but actually answers the question: **edit.**

Comment: Welcome to Meta Stack Overflow! This is not a forum. In a few upvotes' time you'll be able to make proper GLaDOS references; in the meantime, please use the "Post answer" button for actual answers only.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is appropriate to comment after so much time as passed since this answer was posted, but... how is it that a last visit within 30 **days** is *relatively recent*, while while one within **minutes** is *far back in the past*?

Comment: @A.P. Question timestamp + minutes != Now - minutes

Comment: I see, thanks. I didn't think posts could be added for review after so much time has passed since they are posted.

Answer (score 9):

**Category**: Nothing but a URL

**Symptom**: Totally unrelated spam

**Example**:

> www.cheapwatches.com

**Policy**: Click through and flag as spam

Answer (score 7):

**Category**: Answers which should be questions

**Symptom**: How can I do [something related]?

**Example**:

> Hi all, I have a similar problem with my Foo which won't compile properly in the following circumstances. I'm going crazy here, someone help pleez!

**Policy**: Click through, comment 'please post a new question' (see below), flag, (don't down-vote if very low rep user?). *There's no point commenting if the user hasn't been back in months*

**Example comment**:

```
[Optional: Welcome to SiteName!] If you have another question, please ask it by
clicking the [Ask Question](http://siteurlhere/questions/ask?tags=tag1+tag2+tag3)
button. I have taken the time to fill in the tags for you :)
```

Answer (score 6):

**Category**: Answers which should be comments

**Symptom**: Additional information added by OP

**Example**:

> John that doesn't work, here is the code for my snozzleTheFrubuts() method...

**Policy**: Click through, comment 'please edit your original question' (see below), flag, (don't down-vote if very low rep user?). *There's no point commenting if the user hasn't been back in months*

**Example comment**:

```
[Optional: Welcome to SiteName!] Please use the "Post answer" button for 
actual answers only. You should modify your original question to add additional 
information.
```

Comment: Usually I'll copy the information into the user's question as well with text like "Edit: Copied from OPs answer" or similar.

Answer (score 5):

**Category**: Answers which should be comments

**Symptom**: Requests for OP to provide additional information

**Example**:

> question is confusing make it in points so easy to understand and answer

**Policy**: This is a tough one, because if the user doesn't have sufficient rep to comment, they don't really have much choice. *If you are feeling generous* create the comment yourself, then flag. Moderators can choose to turn it into a comment. (See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78507/what-is-the-correct-way-of-providing-feedback-on-a-question-without-posting-an-an) related question.)

**Example comment**:

```
[Optional: Welcome to SiteName!] This is really a comment, not an answer. With 
a bit more rep, you will be able to post comments. For the moment I've added the 
comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.
```

Comment: Seems like there's really only one option right now - flag for moderator attention as "not an answer".  Since this happens a lot, it may be useful to (1) make "should be a comment" its own separate option(s) ("should be a comment to question", "should be a comment to answer XYZ") from the other "not an answer"-type selection, and/or (2) given it automated treatment (e.g. if N people mark as "should be a comment to question, it becomes a comment to question).

Comment: There is a practical problem here, in that sometimes we need much information, which might result in exhaustive scripts - I had such situations, but rarely on Unix&Linux or AskUbuntu, in the context of network settings. A multi step investigating-the-error " (lspci, lsmod, ifconfig, cat /etc/resolv.conf, ...)" guide can be very useful for multiple users, which find the question, but I admit, it's not an answer. But it is unreadable if spread over 3 comments with multiple code invocations, sample output, how to read the output and so on. I don't have an answer for this problem.

Answer (score 4):

**Category**: Answers which should be questions

**Symptom**: I have the same problem

**Example**:

> Yeh i have the exact same problem did you ever find solution to this problem?

**Policy**: Click through, comment 'this is not an answer' (see below), flag, (don't down-vote if very low rep user?). *There's no point commenting if the user hasn't been back in months*. Note: very low rep users can't [upvote questions](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up), so there's no point including that advice if you comment.

**Example comment**:

```
[Optional: Welcome to SiteName!] If you have a NEW question, please ask it by
clicking the [Ask Question](http://siteurlhere/questions/ask)
button. If you have sufficient reputation, you may upvote the question. 
Alternatively, 'star' it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.
```

Answer (score 3):

**Category**: Very Short (one line) Answers

**Symptom**: Answer *does* solve the problem

**Example**:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable LEFT JOIN myOthertable ON myTable.name=myOtherTable.name
```

**Policy**: Ignore the post, because it's OK? *I was confused, I thought "flag for removal" meant removal **from the list of posts to review**, not **removal from the site altogether!***

**Alternatively**: If you're feeling generous, edit the answer into shape...

Comment: Can you explain the rationale that makes these bad answers? Getting everyone thinking the same about it may help decide the policy.

Comment: @BertF I'm suggesting that they're not bad answers, but the show up under `/review` so we should remove them from there because they're OK. I'm really looking for guidance here.

Comment: @BertF it was just explained to me that **I totally misunderstood what "Flag for removal means!!!** So, sorry about that!

Comment: I consider this to be a "bad answer" if the questioner has actually asked for an explanation of why they're having the problem... With no explanation, they haven't provided what the questioner actually needs.

Comment: Why - supposed it is an useful and complete answer - would it be generous to add some noise? I suggest upvoting instead (maybe as a new answer to this thread).

Answer (score 3):

**Category**: Very Short (one line) Answers

**Symptom**: Answer *does* solve the problem

**Example**:

```
egrep -v "[^fobar]" FILE
```

**Policy**: Upvote the correct answer.

(Category+Symptom are a shameless copy of "The Unhandled Exc"'s answer, but my policy is very different.

Comment: It probably refers to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75969/63550).

Answer (score 2):

**Category:** Suggested edits gone wrong

**Symptom:** Editor is reckless with the OP's original content

**Example:**

*Original:*

> I heard that you can't copy text (in the browser) without using
>   something like Flash; so, is there a way to select text by using an
>   anchor and JavaScript or jQuery?

*Reviewed:*

> I heard that you can't copy text **<del>(in the browser) without</del>** using
>   something like Flash; so, is there a way to select text by using an
>   anchor and JavaScript **<del>or jQuery</del>**?

**Policy:** Click <kbd>Reject</kbd>, and mark as "Radical Change".

Answer (score 2):

**Category:** Questions that are a tangled mess

**Symptom:** Cluttered with redundant content

**Example:**

*Original:*

> I heard that you can't copy text (in the browser) without using
>   something like Flash; so, is there a way to select text by using an
>   anchor and JavaScript or jQuery?

*Edited:*

> I heard that you can't copy text (in the browser) without using
>   something like Flash; so, is there a way to select text by using an
>   anchor and JavaScript or jQuery?
>
> **Edit:**
>   Maybe it's possible using HTML 5?
>
> **Update:**
>   I tried with HTML 5, and couldn't find any way of making it possible.
>
> **Notice:**
>   My birthday is coming next week, so any answer is welcomed by then, thanks!

**Policy:** Click <kbd>Improve</kbd>, remove redundant content, and leave a comment to explain the edit.