# Is the comment limitation on new users counter-productive?

Tags: discussion, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Revisit “New users can't ask for clarifications except as answers”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120454/revisit-new-users-cant-ask-for-clarifications-except-as-answers)

I find it strange that new users are banned from offering comments on questions particularly if their entire goal from the outset is to provide answers to questions and not necessarily ask any of their own.  Since SO prides itself on limiting the types of "answers" you can give, it seems the only way to get clarification on a certain question (if ambiguous) or provide a tip/pointer (but not necessarily a full-fledged answer) is through the comments system.  But, unless your reputation "precedes" you, you're disallowed the "privilege."

Comment: I'm sure this is a dupe... in fact I'm positive.  Just want to put in my 2 cents..

Comment: Every time someone comes to meta and complains about "snark-attacks" they never provide examples. :( Maybe I just don't hang out in the right tags to see it?

Comment: I see them all the time, just browsing from a google search in one area or another... There was one I was involved with that got deleted altogether, so I can't provide a link...

Comment: The main reason for requiring some rep for comments is that comments don't bump the post (and thus don't attract attention to the post), thus spam comments would be _very_ hard to find. And yes it's a privilege, one that's very easy to get, SO gets a mega-bazillion questions per second, go out there and answer some, you'll get 50 rep soon enough.

Comment: I'm not here to "answer questions."  I'm here to provide the small expertise that I have.  I don't give a crap about points.  I just want to contribute in areas where I can help.  Unfortunately, the system won't allow me without some arduous run-around.

Comment: Whatever guys, there's not much more I can say, and I'm not spending any more time on it.  Just count it as one more drop in the bucket if you want. Or think on it, and maybe talk at a higher level.  I don't know how that process works.  Either way, I'm tired.  Have a nice evening! :)

Comment: Well if you are not here to answer questions, you can always try asking questions. If you aren't interested in that either, perhaps a Q&A site is not for you...

Comment: @Yannis Awesome, yours is precisely the attitude to which I'm referring.  Where does that even come from?

Comment: Funktron, I've removed a portion of your question that's not helpful. You may roll back my change if you wish, but I strongly encourage you to keep discussions here constructive.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Hey, if you know how business is done here, I'll let you drive. I was just trying to vocalize the reasoning for the question... and my experience in general.

Comment: @Funktron, you seem more level-headed than most people who come here to question the way the system works, which I appreciate. It's why I'm responding to you instead of dismissing you as a crank. That said, why are you just immediately pooh-poohing Yannis's position? It'd be one thing if you explained _why_ you didn't like what he said, but -- and my apologies if I'm misreading -- it sounds like you're presupposing that he's not worth discussing the issue with.

Comment: @PopularDemand I dismissed his proposal that a Q/A site may not be for me because I thought I had made it clear that my intent was not simply to play the "question answering game" and rack up points.  My real intent is to read questions as I browse and offer help where I can.  Oftentimes, that means leaving a comment, and I'm unable to do it.  My main gripe is that I HAVE tried to play by the rules (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896060/amazon-flexible-payments-exception-caller-input-exception-invalid-signature/10264482#10264482) and earn points but despite the investment, I'm stymied.

Comment: @PopularDemand My referenced link has received numerous upvotes since starting this discussion, but beforehand, was unrecognized.  Anyway, it's not that that particular effort wasn't cared for (seriously, that's fine, and is entirely expected to some degree), it's that I want to continue to contribute and I'm always left frustrated with a handicapped ability to participate, even though it should be clear by now that I'm not a spammer.

Comment: Something you should keep in mind is that reputation is *not* the ultimate reason Stack Overflow exists (that'd be a pretty shallow reason). The founders of SO wanted to increase the amount of good information out there. Reputation is one tool to do that. In this case, the site (to be anthropomorphic) wants to see that you know what kinds of commentary is appropriate. The way is does that is by forcing you to contribute enough *actual* questions and answers that you get some upvotes. Nothing personal - just the model this site's chosen.

Comment: Okay, I can get on board with you as far as "this system is imperfect." I'm not convinced that reducing the comment threshold is the correct solution to the problem, though. It's been in effect for a while, and when you look at the big picture, the site functions fine. (And yes, I realize it's not much comfort to think about the big picture when your small part of the picture is the one with problems.)

Comment: That said, I understand it's frustrating. It's frustrating for me and the other self-appointed janitors here, deleting or flagging the n'th *"This isn't really an answer, but I don't have enough rep to comment"* non-answers. Given the justification provided in the answers to the other questions on this topic, *what solution would you suggest*?

Comment: I don't know jack about AWS, so I can't say much about your answer, but it looks pretty comprehensive and well-thought-out, which I can't say about as many answers as I would like. You seem like you'd be a valuable contributor to the site if you decide to stay, and for what it's worth, I hope you do.

Comment: Well I don't know if my business here is to suggest new features, or somehow expect the whole back-end system to change because of my personal experience, but I do think there should be another avenue for participation from the less-reputed among us.  Maybe you enforce CAPTCHAS on all low-rep users' comments?  Does that help?

Comment: @PopularDemand Thanks for the compliments.  I do appreciate the notice.

Comment: It is absolutely your business to suggest new features, [as long as you keep this in mind](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) (it's often discouraging for new folks, but shouldn't be). CAPTCHAs are really an anti-bot measure, where the comment rep-limit exists to force new users to hang around for a bit and prove themselves before commenting.

Comment: I can see the commenting system as an effective reward for positive contributions to the community (I'm reminded of the way IRC used to work in the 90's with +v) but the problem is that it's critical in the Q/A process and is limiting in a way that it shouldn't be.  Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems that the way comments are USED on this site was an evolution of behavior rather than a design focus.  If that's the case, there needs to be a new construct, a 1-1 vessel for people to directly communicate with the author of the question and at least request elaboration.  An elaborate button?

Comment: @Funktron An elaborate button wouldn't work, "please elaborate" is not really helpful if you don't tell the OP on what exactly they should elaborate. But if you had the ability to tell them (at 1 rep), then we're back where we started, the spam problem. That said, yes it's more of a counter measure to certain behaviors rather than a productive feature. Welcome to the internet ;( (no sarcasm here, just sad realization).

Comment: @YannisRizos I was thinking you thwart spam with a CAPTCHA and give an input limit on the elaboration focus (maybe 100 chars).  That way you're still "on the outside looking in" with regard to generalized banter in the comments but you get to clue the author in about what kind of additional info you need to assist.  The author responds by updating his/her post.

Comment: Good start, @Funktron. How would you deal with a poor question that generates dozens of "please elaborate" comments? Publicly posted comments tend to be naturally rate-limited, as new potential commenters are deterred by all the existing comments (well, to a certain degree). That governing process wouldn't exist for these private messages. And what about harassment (this has an obvious solution or two).

Comment: Well... The thing is, will it be worth the trouble? As I already said getting 50 rep is a pretty easy thing to do for most - don't know when you last checked but you are just an approved edit away (fix a post, get 2 rep, comment everywhere! ;).

Comment: Oh, I couldn't resist. Upvoted a good question back to 0. You can comment now. If you feel like it, organize your thoughts on low-rep commenting (review other similar requests too, many of which are over on the right under the "Related" header) and post a feature request. I suggest waiting until this post has scrolled off the front page, though.

Comment: Told you it was easy!

Comment: If you post a count on the elaboration requests, you might see some rate-limiting for volume.  I suppose you could also publicly display the requests from "comment-approved" users or just only show the "elaborate button" to new users and leave comments how they are.  The purpose here is just to give new users SOME way to communicate with question authors.  They don't need to sit any higher on the totem pole.  Abuse I think is handled the way it is with public comments... if you send an elaboration request, it's visible to all mods and if you're flagged, as a new guy, you're toast.

Comment: Thanks for the votes guys! I'm honored :)

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I'll start gathering and do just that.  Thanks for entertaining the discussion.

Answer (score 4):

> I find it strange that new users are banned from offering comments on questions particularly if their entire goal from the outset is to provide answers to questions and not necessarily ask any of their own.

[Comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) might easily be the most coveted privilege on Stack Overflow. Without it, you really cannot fully participate. I **do** get that.

But I'll say to you what I said to everyone else that opened a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) about this:

Without some kind of threshold that prevents new user accounts from commenting on all questions, anybody in control of a botnet could flood Stack Overflow with literally **millions of comments**.

It doesn't matter how insightful your comments would be or how much the current situation sucks for you, it just can't make up for the fact that Stack Overflow would drown in spam, just as so many other sites already have.

Add to this that it's **really easy** to gain `50` rep:

- `+5` rep for an upvote on a question of yours.
- `+2` for accepting an answer.
- `+10` rep for an upvote on an answer of yours.
- `+15` rep for getting an answer of yours accepted.
- `+2` for getting a suggested edit approved.

Comment: Well, to be fair, the same could be said of answers and (to a lesser degree, given their greater visibility) questions. The same last-resort protections apply: rate limiting. I would be surprised if comments are not rate-limited today.

Comment: I get the spam thing.  Trust me, I think everyone coming from a programming standpoint understands the technical risks/requirements.  There's got to be a better implementation out there though.  I mean... I provided this solution to a question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896060/amazon-flexible-payments-exception-caller-input-exception-invalid-signature/10264482#10264482) solely for the prospect of "earning points."  But, (up until just now) that effort was entirely unrewarded.  And that's fine.  It just seems terribly difficult to achieve a basic need here.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta The difference being that answers bump the post, appear in /review and can be down voted, on smaller sites we catch spammers in seconds. It's not just the rate limit.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: Plus, answers have CAPTCHAs. Of course, I don't know how the algorithms work, but I can imagine CAPTCHAs for **every** post while Stack Overflow is under attack.

Comment: @Yannis: I can see the point of that on smaller sites. On SO, I see /review and wince.

Comment: @Funktron: The by far easiest way to earn a little amount of rep are suggested edits. The question you answered is among the less popular tags `[amazon-web-services]` and it was already old when you answered it. Add to this that the question itself is a little localized (like all support questions). Your answer looks good to me, but the question itself isn't necessarily a rep magnet...