# What about allowing users with low rep posting comments to any question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, comments, new-users

It is quite common that users with no rep. want to react to old questions. Many times it is something like: *"I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?"*. They posting it as an answer and I'm flagging it as *"Not an answer - should be a comment"*. I would also like to notify the user that he should post it as a comment next time but posting comments to questions is priviledge of users with 50+ reputation. At the moment I just adding comment that if the user have the similar problem he should ask a new question and link the unanswered one. But I'm not sure that user will see my comment if a moderator deletes flagged answer.

So how to handle these scenarios? Should be all users allowed to post comments to questions (or at least to old questions with not accepted answer)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [New users can't ask for clarifications except as answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51926/new-users-cant-ask-for-clarifications-except-as-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for your precise example, it shouldn't even be a comment. "Me too" doesn't help anybody.

My current policy for this particular case is:

> If you have a NEW question, please ask
>   it by clicking the Ask Question
>   button. If you have sufficient
>   reputation, you may upvote the
>   question. Alternatively, "star" it as
>   a favorite and you will be notified of
>   any new answers

[Here are some ideas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74194/how-to-review-can-we-agree-on-a-review-policy) for the other cases that may present themselves, and even (shameless plug) [a userscript to help you remember](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/pro-forma-comments).

Comment: But perhaps it helps the asking user if owner of original question shares the final solution or workaround. Nevermind If I add comment and answer is deleted, will the user be able to see the comment?

Comment: @Lasislav, ok, but that would be in the (hypothetical) case where the OP *did* find the solution but forgot to post it on the site. From what I have understood, users *do* get notified, even if their answer gets deleted. I tend to comment and flag.