# Taking screenshots of deleted answers on meta sites is considered bad behavior?

Tags: support, etiquette, meta, deleted-answers, screenshot

I've answered a meta question - [Disappearing comments and answers on meta.](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233/disappearing-comments-and-answers-on-meta) - with a screenshot of that deleted post.

But someone warned me, because I took a screenshot without permission from poster.

So, is taking a screenshot of a deleted answer on a Meta site considered bad behavior?

Note: I personally don't agree with the poster who warned me.

Comment: FWIW: in the comments on the linked answer, you use [this answer from Jeff Atwood](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86377) in your argument... I just want to point out that [Eggs McLaren is a puppet test account Jeff uses to validate "regular user" stuff on the site](http://stackoverflow.com/users/8/eggs-mclaren).

Comment: @fretje, how about acctman, pleasedontbelong, Dagon? Those does not seems like test accounts.

Comment: the other screenshot isn't a deleted post... only the Eggs McLaren one is.

Comment: @fretje, thanks, you're right. but I liked to ask about etiquette, and now found the way to do it.

Comment: The part that bothers me is that your red, freehand circle isn't a circle and it's not freehand -- unless your hands are incredibly steady.  Please get with the meme: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I could go on about the CC Wiki license that says, technically, this is allowed - their content is still on the site after all. So let's put aside the technical aspect and look at the social aspect.

I wouldn't go around digging up everything everyone writes and ends up deleting, of course, *but you aren't doing that*.

You're just showing a deleted answer, *which you wanted to do to highlight the portion of the deleted answer that shows it was deleted by the author*. You did this to strongly assert this with physical proof that goes beyond just word-of-mouth that the post was self-deleted, and not moderator deleted.

Like [Aleadam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95368/taking-screenshot-on-deleted-answers-on-meta-sites-are-considered-bad-behavior/95370#95370) and [Changeling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95368/taking-screenshot-on-deleted-answers-on-meta-sites-are-considered-bad-behavior/95369#95369), it would possibly be seen as more respectful, so to speak, to blur out the content of the answer or the answerer's name - the fact it was self-deleted generally means that the author doesn't want the post to be seen. But I wouldn't call it bad behavior to neglect to do so, not in a scenario like this where your intent was clearly to focus on a different element altogether.

Answer (score 8):

There might be many reasons why a user deleted the post. Some may relate to his/her privacy, and that should be respected. What I would do is to add some blur to the username and keep visible only the relevant part to make a point.

Answer (score 6):

I think the user in question needs a hug. There have been plenty of times where screenshots have been posted of deleted questions. Probably should go back and blur out the name. At some point, someone should have taken the high road between you and him. It seems emotions got the best of both of you.