# Why was this answer deleted?

Tags: support, moderation

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297107/removing-characters-between-brackets/7297239#7297239 (The link is for 10k users.)

I've looked at the FAQ but don't see a reason for deletion that applies.

Would it be possible for the moderators to comment on answers they are about to delete first, and give an explanation, before going crazy with the delete button?

For what it's worth, I don't mind people pointing out when I make a mistake, so that I can learn from it. However, I found having my answer deleted with no explanation at all a very off-putting, negative experience.

Comment: Your "answer" was not one. If would have been acceptable as a comment.

Comment: Any 10k who can make a screenshot? I thought deletions (not by the owner) [nowadays showed a link to the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86316/how-to-educate-people-about-non-answers/86377#86377)?

Comment: @Arjan The owner of the post does see a link if it is deleted, but I think it's only shown to the owner.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You answered a question that was tagged:

- [c](/questions/tagged/c) [array](/questions/tagged/array) [function](/questions/tagged/function) [pointers](/questions/tagged/pointers)

with the answer:

> Why do you want to do this in C? I would think this task is much better suited to a tool like `sed`.

Perhaps you imagine that you were "thinking outside the box" but you fundamentally violated the constraints of the question.  You **started** to answer a different question:

> How do you solve this problem using the tool or language of your choice?

Even if that **were** the question, your answer was that the problem *could* be solved using `sed`, but didn't even provide the actual solution, e.g. something like:

```
sed 's/\[[^]]*\]//g'
```

It's very simple.  You have to **try to actually solve the problem as stated in order to qualify as an answer**, otherwise your post is subject to deletion as **not an answer**.

Comment: Thats hardly grounds to delete his answer though?  Downvote it yes, but not delete it.

Comment: @Toby, then why would there be a flag "Not an answer"? Posts flagged that way, [are subject for deletion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion).

Comment: @Toby: Voting is for legitimate answers; flagging is for everything else.  Suppose the question is what is `2+2`?  If the answer is `2+2=4` => upvote; `2+2=5` => downvote; _try meditation_ => flag as **not an answer**.

Comment: I would have thought "you're using the wrong tool for the job" to be a lot more useful to the asker than some C code (since it seemed they were asking for C out of ignorance of other options). It would have to me. But ok, thanks for the thoughtful explanation.

Comment: @user152743: It **is** potentially useful and you can suggest such options as a comment.  In fact you can ask whether the asker would consider such alternatives in comments before answering.

Answer (score 7):

We don't go *crazy* with any buttons, however users that don't read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) or links that appear in an effort to explain things are known to drive us a little batty.

Your answer was removed in conjunction with a very low quality post. Additionally, it really wasn't an answer. It was *related* to the question at hand, but it didn't *answer* the question at hand.

Since the question was going away, converting your answer to a comment would have been a little silly.

Comment: Usually it says who deleted a question.. how come it shows only "deleted 4 hours ago" for the Question?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard I've noticed that before. I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: I guess it happens when it's deleted by someone without account e.g. the OP of that question but I doubt he deleted his own question.