# Imgur's Amsterdam CDN giving 504 Gateway Timeout for many images

Tags: support, images, imgur

This is merely a "for your information" for those using the Amsterdam Imgur server and not seeing all images. Today, that Amsterdam server gives me an error for many (but certainly not all) images. It has already been reported to Imgur.

For example, [some image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWFzG.png) gets me an HTML error page:

```
$ curl -verbose https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWFzG.png > test.png
[...]
HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Timeout
Content-Type: text/html
Server: ECAcc (ams/489C)
Content-Length: 357
```

For the very same URL, [Web-Sniffer reports](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWFzG.png) a different server, which does return the image:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/png
Server: ECAcc (fra/D4A4)    
X-Cache: HIT    
Content-Length: 64960
```

Even just going to https://i.stack.imgur.com fails for me.

I'm sure Imgur will fix this.

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out! We had been wrestling with this mystery until we thought of a CDN.

Comment: @Cerberus, for me, all is fine again.

Comment: Yes, for me too! Cool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is Alan from Imgur. There are some issues with people not being able to load images, specifically in Europe and The Netherlands. I've contacted Edgecast (the network used to display the images) and they're aware of what's happening and are working to get it fixed.

Sorry for the trouble, but it looks like things are out of my hands at this point. However, Edgecast is usually really on top of things, so I expect this should be resolved soon.

Comment: Things are working fine again, for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for contacting Edgecast, it is working fine for me now, too. It was all so mysterious because it only affected some images, not all. Apparently the CDN deals with certain images itself, forwards the request to the main servers for other images?

Comment: Or, @Cerberus, it caches and then has to contact the main server for unknown content? It did seem to affect all new images, and some old images. Oddly enough, only the first of two images from [some old post failed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86316/how-to-educate-people-about-non-answers/86377#86377). I'd expect both images to have been requested the same number of times.

Comment: @Arjan: Hmm I only saw it failing on images posted in chat, including old ones; images in the few answers that I browsed seemed unaffected. The pattern seems complicated.