# Preventing the "Your Answer" box from showing when answering a question

Tags: feature-request, answers

Every time I click on the answer box below a question, a box shows up saying:

> ### Your Answer
>
> Thanks for contributing an answer to Stack Overflow!
>
> - Please be sure to *answer the question*. Provide details and share your research!
>
> But *avoid* …
>
> - Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers.
> - Making statements based on opinion; back them up with references or personal experience.
>
> To learn more, see our [tips on writing great answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Image:
[image: The Your Answer box]

I've tried clicking the "ok" button a couple of times, assuming it would either set a cookie in my browser or even change a setting on my account, but the thing just keeps popping up. Because I think I get how I am supposed to answer now that I've read it a thousand times, I'd like to be able to just hide it permanently instead of having to hide it temporarily every time I want to answer a question. <del>Is this possible?</del>

Could you please make a kind of checkbox on the "Your Answer" box, or a setting in the preference, that you can manually disable this box? Otherwise, could you make it hide automatically after clicking "ok" more than a certain amount of times? I can appreciate the suggestions, but it doesn't make sense to me to keep showing that message after somebody's clicked "ok" a couple of times already.

Comment: I believe it is rep dependent, I just don't know what the threshold is.

Comment: Don't remember of this popup, even with new browser/IP, might be reputation related indeed.

Comment: Appears to be new feature, there's also a bug where the "tips on writing great answers" always link to Stack Overflow, even in other sites. Anyway asking to change it so it's hidden after one "ok" is feature request.

Comment: The threshold is 100; see [How to educate people about non-answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86316/how-to-educate-people-about-non-answers/86377#86377)

Comment: @Arjan good find! :)

Comment: [Not really](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks+for+contributing+an+answer+to+Stack+Overflow%21%22), @ShadowWizard ;-)