# Should the pro-forma comments script be integrated into SO?

Tags: feature-request, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formal adoption of Pro-forma comments script into SE engine proper](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117963/formal-adoption-of-pro-forma-comments-script-into-se-engine-proper)

With 4k+ questions a day, there is an endless stream of new users repeating the same mistakes - be it domain-specific mistakes inside their code, or SO-specific mistakes in content and formatting. If it's not a closevote-worthy problem, the way to point out those mistakes is adding a comment. But at some point, everybody gets tired of repeating the same comment  over and over and over.

The most practical solution I've found to the problem is Benjol's brilliant [pro-forma comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) script. It stores a list of templates that you can quickly insert into the comment field. (It even automatically adds "Welcome to Stack Overflow!" when the OP is new.)  This script does a great job helping with posts with recurring problems like missing code, SQL injections present, "doesn't work" problem descriptions, et cetera., cases for which you don't want to write a new comment every time.

I'm asking myself should the functionality be implemented a SO feature, say available to 2k+ users?

Possible advantages:

- Centralized storage of comment templates would take away the need to rebuild your templates list on every client you use.
- The possibility to have a list of community-curated comment templates, leading to overall higher quality - creating a good comment template (with a polite greeting, an explanation of the issue, and some helpful links) isn't completely trivial. (This would complement the existing functionality of having your own comment templates, not replace it.)
- The collection of usage data (how often did users insert the "please show some code" comment?") can be helpful for future UI decisions