# Does the originator of a removed answer receive the comments to his answer?

Tags: support

Recently, I flagged an answer as `not an answer` and added a comment to the answer.

Later (before the originator removed also his question) I could see that the flagged answer was deleted (flag was helpful) but the comment was moved up to the question.

So I'm asking myself: did the writer of the (flagged and therefore removed) answer receive my comment?

Comment: Currently, the user won't get a notification about the comment if the answer is deleted before he visits the site again. I proposed to change this behaviour a while ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133729/treat-comments-on-deleted-posts-from-moderating-users-like-comments-from-diamond

Comment: @MadScientist: +1 from me for that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only if he was faster than the moderator, and read it before it was deleted.

I believe moderators can leave comments that will reach the OP, but not us mere mortals.

Comment: but this is not really satisfying. How would I tell the answerer what he's done wrong? In that case he added an answer where he complained about a potential copyright violation of the question (some copyright notice was removed from posted code) and I pointed him to a question on META where it was described what to do in that case.

Comment: @eckes: It's up to the moderator to include such info in their own comment.

Comment: Seems we have to choose. Either give the poster a hint, and hope he fixes the post, or leave it to moderation.

Comment: ... or vote for MadScientists proposal.