# Keep "convert to comment" button enabled if the answer does not have a freeform comment

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, convert-to-comment

Since SO now has ["native" support for common comments on bad answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143640/147015) it would be nice if those comments would not disable the "convert to comment" button in the mod queue.

It could even improve the "not an answer" queue by automatically displaying answers there which were not flagged but got one of the related comments.

To make it even better that feature should not rely on the comment being posted via the new tool but check the string itself (in a way that also matches the comments created by the [popular userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/3360))