# Review beta: auto-comment small change

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review

Right now there's a "No Comment" radio button in the auto-comment dialog for deleting a question in Review-beta. However, it's possible to just vote to delete and not leave a comment by hitting the delete button. It seems like it would easier to use if there wasn't a "No Comment" choice, but rather a revised wording on the delete button (like "delete with no comment" if no radio button is selected).[image]

Sorry for the messy mouse writing ;) I know this is a small change but I figured since this just showed up it smaller suggestions wouldn't be so bad.

Comment: Wow, auto-comments...

Comment: @Benjol: look familiar? ;-)

Comment: @Shog9, eh, kinda. The jackass in me is hesitating between being indignant or very proud :)

Comment: @Benjol I've been using your auto-comment thing for a while now, glad that they put it in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the next build "No comment" will be the default selection.

Answer (score 5):

[Radio buttons can't be unselected](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13511/why-is-it-impossible-to-deselect-html-radio-inputs/13513#13513); it doesn't make sense to have "unselected" mean something. I really think this should remain as an explicit option. Just because I pick one of the other options doesn't mean I should never be able to pick the no comment option; that's effectively what a "no radio selection" implementation would mean.

Changing the delete button's text is also dangerous; at a glance it could seem the *only* option is delete with no comment, since that's how the button appears by default. It appears to make the form meaningless, then suddenly changes if you select something.

Comment: You're right about the radio buttons; maybe a better design would be to change the radio buttons to normal buttons and remove the delete button altogether... Anything that removes non-review work from review is good in my book. I see you have a lot of rep in UX so you probably know what's up.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like an easy fix would be just to have the 'no comment' radio button selected by default.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't think of that.