# Frequently used "new user" suggestions

Tags: feature-request, comments

I have seen many more experienced users reply to new users' questions with links and well formed suggestions on how to accept an answer, how to write a good question, and other helpful-to-newbies comments.

I was wondering if there will ever be a feature where someone with high enough rep --say 5k, can create canned responses for certain types of questions, and then users with 1k or higher can suggest those common responses for the question.

Perhaps it should be like editing where inexperienced users get to "suggest" and it will go into a suggestions queue where more experienced users can vote to accept or reject the suggestion for the user.

I have tried to emulate other more experienced users in some of my comments, explaining how to accept an answer, linking to [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and other comments I have seen on poor questions, or other common new user follies, but sometimes I find myself in a position where I can't remember the link to good resources, so I have to go searching through my past answers/comments.

I tried to search for a similar question or concept here on meta, but I did not see anything like what I am suggesting. If this has been asked, or if a similar feature has been proposed, please let me know where that question is.

**EDIT**

In light of comments, I have removed "improve your acceptance rate" from my list of good suggestions. Perhaps if the comment system sees "improve and acceptance" in the same sentence, it should suggest that they don't post it to reduce discouraged comments. Like a "this comment seems to be discouraged, post anyway?" sort of warning.

Comment: I would not include "improve your acceptance rate" as a helpful comment. You might want to take that out. <-- helpful comment right there. ;)

Comment: I often wish there was an auto-comment feature available. (and FWIW the acceptance rate message would be useful as well - as long as its constructive and helps the user learn how things work on SE).

Comment: I specifically added the "improve your acceptance rate" because I see people reluctant to answer questions if the users' acceptance rate is too low

Comment: @Greg Perhaps you are unaware, but comments in the exact format you list (i.e. "improve your acceptance rate") are explicitly discouraged. What's more, they are even automatically nuked with a single flag, precisely because they are discouraged. But let me not distract from your otherwise valid request.

Comment: This [repository of useful pro forma comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments) is a good place to copy paste comments from.

Comment: @assylias That is a great resource, thank you.

Comment: +1 for auto-comment system

Comment: This will, indeed, make it much faster for multiple users to post content saying the same thing.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117963/formal-adoption-of-pro-forma-comments-script-into-se-engine-proper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some tools for that already:

- The new [review system](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) encourages you to add a canned comment (from a fixed list) when recommending an answer for deletion.
- The [AutoReviewComments userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/167534) allows you to manage and easily post canned comments.
- As mentioned above, there is a [Repository of useful pro forma comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136609/167534) that can be used with the userscript.

There has been a [request to integrate that userscript as a native tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117963/167534), but it's [been considered implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137363/167534) as the dialog currently available on the review system.