# Welcome text shortcut for new users with poor posts

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers, new-users, low-quality-posts

A problem I've seen on both [Sci-fi](http://scifi.stackexchange.com) and [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/) is poor first user posts. Specifically, the user (who  typically has a rep of 1) will post an answer:

- which is rambling / ranting answer interspersed with CAPITAL LETTERS to highlight particularly parts of their opinion (the entire post is typically *their opinion*)
- there will be no references to back up the answer
- there will be no formatting (apart from the aforementioned upper case); it will be one block of text

The communities handle this in a fairly standard (and I think, very good) way:

1. The post will be flagged (it may also be downvoted).
2. An established user will add text to welcome the new user, explain that the answer is not what we're looking for and refer them to [about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) and / or [help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help).
3. If it is unsalvageable, a moderator will delete the answer.

Having done 1 & 2 many times, I think there is a fairly easy way to save some time here. My suggestion is:

**Add a shortcut, like *[w]*, so that when it is entered as a comment, standard welcome text is added.**

This would be an extension to the [already extensive comment formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

For example, if a user entered **[w]** (and / or **[welcome]**) in a comment, this text would appear:

> Welcome to [site-name]. This is not the kind of answer we're looking for here. Please look at the [about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) page to find out how this site differs from other forums.

Optionally, we could restrict this to users of a certain rep (eg 200 on Beta sites, 500 on established sites).

Comment: Highly related [Add data.SE style “magic links” to comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments) especially when combined with [Formal adoption of Pro-forma comments script into SE engine proper](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117963/formal-adoption-of-pro-forma-comments-script-into-se-engine-proper).

Comment: Looks like something that [AutoReviewComments](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) handles.

Comment: A shortcut to get the (already existing) auto-comments you get in the review queues could be nice.