# semiautomated "being nice to newbies"

Tags: feature-request, new-users

I've only been a member of stackoverflow for less than two months, and active answering questions for a little more than one. But I'm already getting quite tired of the flood of badly written, badly stated questions, that contain no code at all or very long sequences of unreadable uncommented code that can only work on the poster's machine. In such cases one can hardly do anything more than to leave a comment: "Please describe your own research efforts, state clearly what the concrete problem is, if possible include minimal non-working code." etc. Sometimes I do exactly that, but sometimes I'm impatient, maybe ignore the question, maybe downvote, maybe leave a snippy comment. I know, I know, I shouldn't do that, "be nice to newbies", I'm all for it.

So, my question is: *Could there be some additional buttons or something like text macros that make it easier to quickly leave a nice, polite comment along the lines described above?* In a way, this would be similar to flagging, except that in this case it is a communication directed at the poster only, without practical consequences, giving her/him a chance to improve the question before it is downvoted or closed?

There's one caveat though: I think that the text one gets when a question is closed is far too unfriendly, brusque and uninformative, especially if there is no accompanying personal comment, especially if one is a new user. (I know some consider this hypersensitive, but I'd consider people who say so to be emotionally … – no, I don't want to be rude). This means, if such a semiautomatic response mechanism is implemented, the text needs to be *really* friendly, clear, and helpful, not only saying what is expected of them but also why (possibly through a link to the FAQ). I'd be happy to help drafting. :-)

Comment: [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](http://stackapps.com/q/2116)

Comment: Note to self: I should make that link an auto-review comment..

Comment: @MartijnPieters: interesting, thanks!

Comment: Closely related: [Formal adoption of Pro-forma comments script into SE engine proper](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117963) historically, things like this have been proposed before on Meta and rejected by the team. The fear is that any automated commenting solution is going to lead to them being used in a rude way, which actually kinda happened with ["What Stack Overflow is Not"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137795), a FAQ-like collection on Meta that could be linked to in comments

Comment: Just for the record: I did search whether this question had been posed before, and didn't find anything.

Comment: I would try not to grasp to pro-forma comments, if you can at all avoid it. A nicely-worded personalized comment will always be better IMO. But for some cases they are useful.

Comment: @A.Donda yeah, not meaning to put you down for not searching, this is tough to find

Comment: I see many users who have generic responses to poor questions and they just copy paste it into comments.

Comment: @Shoe I'm too lazy for copy paste. ;-)