# Provide UI to post useful comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

A few Stack Exchanges maintain a list of useful comments (I unfortunately can't recollect which one I ran into the other day) that can be used as canned response for newcomers, as do some groups on Stack Overflow [like this one](https://sopython.com/wiki/Useful_Comments).

Would it be possible to get some UI to post useful, pre-written canned responses as comments to speed things up and be more helpful/welcoming when interacting with new users who ask poor quality questions?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)?

Comment: @bluefeet: I believe I haven't. To my credit, though, how am I to discover that when my comment box [looks like this](https://i.imgur.com/fG8GE7s.png)? :-) (And, more to the point, why isn't this on by default?)

Comment: That allows you to customize what default comments you'd like which is much easier then us giving you a standard list.

Comment: On Stack Overflow there is also the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) set: https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments/tree/master/sites/stackoverflow.com

Comment: @bluefeet: any odds you could expand on Cltlija and clarify why this isn't being made part of SO itself in an answer?

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy We sort of [have in the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137363/164200) but at this time we've got no plans to implement this outside of the queues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like [AutoReviewComments - Pro Forma Comments for Stack Exchange](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)?

It's available in StackApps and can be added to Chrome, Firefox or Opera. I don't know that we need an in-house built version of it, though. This version is really nice and allows you to create your own or use pre-written ones. It also lets you mark whether you use a comment on answers or questions (or either), so it reduces the number of choices you have to scroll through.

Comment: Nice to see that it exists. However, I think only a very small part of the users use actually userscripts. Furthermore, posting the same or similar comment a lot times everywhere can be dangerous. Would it been an official feature, it would be okay.

Comment: It's so unfortunate that it isn't available for Safari. Might you be aware if SO tracks what browsers very active users (by which I mean the ones that provide answers and actively moderate) use? I'd be surprised if they correspond to the browsers the general population of visitors use.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy I'm guessing that they do track that but it doesn't really apply to this addon. If you were interested you could attempt to rewrite it for Safari. It's not owned by Stack Overflow, Inc., it's a userscript and I'm pretty sure you can get to the code on [github](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments).

Comment: @peterh " posting the same or similar comment a lot times everywhere can be dangerous" Why? I've never had a problem using canned comments on any SE site.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy I don't mind. Accepts aren't really the "goal". I'm here to help. As a note, Bluefeet *is* staff and gave you the same link :)

Comment: @DavidPostill Currently I am serving a year long cage somewhere, partially for that. It depends on the mods. If there is a problematic content in them, then posting a lot is likely an aggravating circumstance.

Comment: @peterh The comments supplied with AutoReviewComments are not problematic. If you choose to add your own then it is your responsibility to make sure they are not problematic.