# Is it ok to answer a contest post with a list of links to others' content?

Tags: discussion, answers, hyperlinks, link-only-answers

> ## I am not sure if my potential post passes muster.

I have a fun answer to [Time for some more swag!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318910/time-for-some-more-swag) I would like to post the Top 10 Songs of All **Time** list.

This is a top 10 list, so the songs themselves are not my work. My work is compiling them into a list.

On one hand, I feel like this answer is almost too easy, and I am only linking to others' content. On the other hand, it would be fun and useful, and linking to others' content is common on this site.

Things I've tried to answer my own question:

- I looked up [How to reference material written by others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) and [How do I write a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the Help Center, but I'm still not sure if I should post this answer.
- Posts [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers?rq=1) and [Why is linking bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/why-is-linking-bad) seem to say that links are ok as long as context is provided.
- I searched for "[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [fun](/questions/tagged/fun) links" and didn't find anything applicable.

Is there anything else I'm missing? I want to provide only good, clean, StackExchange worthy answers! :-)

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? I want to provide *good* content on this site, so I am open to improving my question.

Comment: Instead of answering "No, it's not OK" some prefer to just downvote. That's part of how meta works. (Not only MSE, any meta site.)

Comment: The compilation list is a personal one, I gather. What are the criteria?  Why is it "fun"? What does of all time mean? Did you start from the 1900s, 50s or 70s? Are the songs pop, rock, punk or a mix. Are opera songs excluded? Yet, they have, arguably, stood the test of time. Will the songs be mostly American? What about the rest of the world?  Will the list be an adaption of one that already exists?  Will any of the songs be about *time*? Is the list funny, quirky, unexpected, original? It's a competition after all....

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Those would all be good things to add to my contest answer!

Comment: There's a [link only answer there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318921/282094) that has stood the test of time, thus far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rule #1 states:

> You can post as many entries as you want *in good faith* as long as they are in line with our [terms of service](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service), [acceptable use policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy) and [code of conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct). This is also a reminder that all user-contributed content falls under our [CC-BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

So yes, contest answers are no different than other Stack Exchange posts in this respect. Of course, originality may influence the way other people are voting. There's really only one way to find out...

Comment: It would be a *good faith* answer for sure. I'm just not sure if there's another good reason to not post the answer.

Comment: Come to think of it, you bring up a good point when you mention originality. Originality could be some people's voting criteria. ;-)

Comment: Your other good point is that the terms for contest answers are similar to that of other answers.